# Missing CDROM from /dev redhat (oracle linux) 6.2

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, oracle-linux

we have installed the minimal install for redhat 6.2 (OL 6.2) on a HP Proliant 380 G8 and there is no `CDROM`, `SDB` or `DVD` listed in `/dev`. If I do `dmesg | more`, I cannot find any reference to it discovering and trying to set up a CDROM device. What do I do next? I know the cd drive works as we installed the OS from that drive. This is a clean install with no mods. Any advice on getting the CD (DVD) drive to show up would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this shows as /dev/sr0. Check for that.